# How can I select only the inside of the mesh?

Tags: faces

I have already tried everything. :( Switching between the modes, used select all by trai-->interior faces. Nothing works in my blend file:(

[image]

Comment: .. While the Solidify modifier is active, the geometry doesn't _have_ an inside. It has a process which _makes_ an inside. So, as you've noted, the Solidify has to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily disabling the subdivision surface modifier and see if that makes it any easier.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your effort and thank you,but its not about that. Guys if anyone have that problem you should apply the modifier if you want to work with the interior side.

Comment: In that case you'll get more response if you upload the blend file so that everyone can offer suggestions. As it is, it's impossible to tell what's going on  to be honest.